# Scheduling multiple delayed local notifications in ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2, cordova-plugins, localnotification

I am always getting the notification for the second object. Notification for the first object is not received. I am using Local Notifications plugin : https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/local-notifications/ from ionic native.
Any help would be great.

```
 LocalNotifications.schedule([{
  id: 1,
  text: 'Multi ILocalNotification 1',
   at: new Date("2017-03-08T10:35:00")

}, {
  id: 2,
  title: 'Local ILocalNotification Example',
  text: 'Multi ILocalNotification 2',     
  at: new Date("2017-03-08T10:40:00")
}]);
```

Comment: new Date("2017-03-08T10:35:00") gives Wed Mar 08 2017 16:20:00 GMT+0545 (Nepal Standard Time). So is then I am not getting the correct time. I removed "T" and is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hello There You'r lucky 
I am using ionic 2 I have just only 1 local notification but it doesnt work when phone is locked and screen is black .

It only works when phone is awake

```
let now = new Date();
    let time1=new Date();

    time1.setMinutes(now.getMinutes()+1) 
        this.timer=time1;
 this.localNotifications.schedule([{
            id:1,
            title: "test",
            text: "tester ?",
            at: time1,
            sound: "file://assets/sound/speed_camera.mp3",

        }]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.